# Python using re to match string in a specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use python re to match a string with a specific pattern. 
The problem I met is, I have this expected sentence:

```
"It is X. not X`
```

X can be anything; A word, or a bunch of word, or number, or digits.

The pattern I build is:

```
It is \w+. not \w+
```

just using

```
string.replace("X", "\w+")
```

It works if `X` is a word, or bunch of words, or int, but not for digits. How can I build my pattern in order to match everything in this pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out, can use `str.replace("X", "(\w+|\d+\.\d+)")` to approach the problem. Hope can help others having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` is a special character in a regular expression that will match any character. So `.+` will match one or more characters.

```
r"It is .+\. not .+"
```

Not that the period is escaped `\.`, this is because in that case, you want to match an actual period.

Comment: Can I use this method for all punctuation? For example in a sentence I have "," , "[" and "]", how can I make them as literally punctuation?

Comment: Yes, any special characters that an expression uses can be escaped in order to match them as normal "literal" characters.

Comment: how can I add in a '\' before every punctuation in a sentence?

Comment: You type it in. If you want to accept any punctuation character you could just use a `.` in the expression, which will match anything.

Answer (score 0):

Because `.+` won't work in some cases, for example

> It is quote. not a double-quote
>
> It is a dog. not a cat

I would use this one instead :

`(?<=It is ).+(?=\.)|(?<=not ).+$`

**Explanation**

`(?<=It is ).+(?=\.)` Any consecutive characters precedeed by `It is`  and followed by a point

`|` OR

`(?<=not ).*$` Any consecutive characters precedeed by `not`  and followed by end of line anchor

`(?<=It is ).*(?=\.)|(?<=not ).*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zt5hhX/2)

Comment: Is there any more general method? because I have more than 50 sentences which may contains X in different positions. I would like to make the sentences as my patterns.

Comment: You should have provided this information. If there are many sentences pattern it could be more difficult to match them this way. Please provide the list of possible sentences in your question and we'll see what's doable.